# How to create a scheduler in jboss 7

Tags: java, jboss, timer, scheduler

i'm trying to create a automatic scheduler in Jboss 7 , which starts automatically once it is deployed . I followed a tutorial on the net . But could'nt get it working. Please help me in resolving this.

The only class I have is AutomaticSchedulerBean.java and the source is as follows :

### AutomaticSchedulerBean.java

```
package test;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.ejb.Schedule;


@Stateless(name="AutomaticSchedulerBean")
public class AutomaticSchedulerBean
{
    @Schedule(dayOfWeek = "*", hour = "*", minute = "*", second = "*/5", persistent = false)
     public void backgroundProcessing()
              {
                       System.out.println("\n\n\t AutomaticSchedulerBean's backgroundProcessing() called....at: "+new Date());
                       System.out.println("called ma boy");
              }
}
```

My ant builds and deploys the jar into standalone\deploy folder . Once its deployed ,the server gives the following info in console

```
 **java:global/schedulerEJB/AutomaticSchedulerBean!test.AutomaticSchedulerBean
  java:app/schedulerEJB/AutomaticSchedulerBean!test.AutomaticSchedulerBean
  java:module/AutomaticSchedulerBean!test.AutomaticSchedulerBean
  java:global/schedulerEJB/AutomaticSchedulerBean
  java:app/schedulerEJB/AutomaticSchedulerBean
  java:module/AutomaticSchedulerBean**
```

But the scheduled job is not processed according to @Schedule. Please help me fix it. Or is there any other way like Using quartz scheduler to fix my problem .

Comment: Are you 100% sure the timer isn't executed? What you have done is correct and as the logs verify, the bean is registrered during deployment. My best guess is that you are using a JBoss dist which doesn't support EJB timers, and just ignores the annotation. What exact version are you using and are you using? And is it the full or web profile?